# base64Decode removes pages from a pdf in base64?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, base64, uint8list

I am using dio package to make a GET request to a server to retrieve a PDF file.

The request is working fine, I get the PDF in base64.

[image: base 64 retrieved ok]

I get the response.data, and I use base64Decode to get the Uint8List, I save the file in the storage.

```
    class FileSaverHelper {
    
      Future<String> save({required String filename, required Uint8List bytes}) async {
    
        final String tempDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
        final filePath = "$tempDir/$filename";
        await File(filePath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    
        return filePath;
    
      }
    
    }
    
    class OpenFileHelper {
    
      final FileSaverHelper fileSaverHelper = Get.find();
    
      Future<void> open({
        required String filename,
        required Future<Uint8List> Function() onDownload
      }) async {
    
        final Uint8List bytes = await onDownload();
        final filePath = await fileSaverHelper.save(
            filename: filename,
            bytes: bytes
        );
    
        if(await File(filePath).exists()){
          OpenFilex.open(filePath);
        }
        
      }

}
```

When I open the PDF it has only the first page and when I test the base64 that the server sends in the site [Base64 to PDF](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), the PDF decoded has the amount of pages correctly (which is two).

[image: the PDF has two pages after decoding]

Why after I use base64Decode(response.data), save the PDF to the storage, open it, it has only the first page but in the site the amount of pages is correct?

Comment: What do you mean? Because without the response.data I can't have the base64.

Comment: without doing base64Decode is it working fine?

Comment: No, if I try to open it directly I get "Error, the file is not a valid pdf", because it's encoded.

Comment: Try opening the file with a different package, such as `pdf_viewer_plugin 2.0.1`, `pdf_render 1.3.6` and  `flutter_pdfview 1.2.5`

Comment: The problem is related to the GET request, the base64 I get already has only one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is with the GET request, since the base64 retrieve by the server only through flutter, the file is retrieved incomplete.